# Dynamic Programming solution for one pile nim game

Tags: python, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, dynamic-programming

I have solved the following problem using dynamic programming: **Little Deepu and his Girlfriend** [1](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/introduction-to-dynamic-programming-1/practice-problems/algorithm/little-deepu-and-his-girlfriend-2/). To paraphrase,

> We have two players Little Deepu and Kate and M items in the bag B,
>   also we have a game set S with N elements, each element of game set is
>   an integer. The game is played as follows, each player takes turn to
>   pick an element from the game set S and removes that number of items
>   from the bag, the player that is unable to remove the items from the
>   bag looses the game. Little Deepu start the game ,If both Little Deepu
>   and Kate play the game optimally, your task is to determine who wins
>   the game.

**Input:**
First line contains a integer T , number of test cases. Each test case contain two lines , first line contain two integer M and N and second line contain elements of S.

**Output:**
For each test case print name of the winner of the game .

Though correct, my solution is exceeding time limit for large inputs. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

```
def winner(n_i, n_t, t_k):
    output = [False]*(n_i + 1)
    for j in t_k:
        output[j    ] = True
    print(output)
    for i in range(1, n_i + 1):
        if not output[j]:
            for j in t_k:
                if j > i:
                    continue
                val = output[i - j]
                if not val:
                    output[i] = True
                    break
    return 'Little Deepu' if output[n_i] else 'Kate' 

num_test = int(input())

for i in range(num_test):
    num_items,num_take_outs = map(int, input().split())
    take_outs = list(map(int, input().split()))
    print(winner(num_items, num_take_outs, take_outs))
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is not well received. `time-limit-exceeded` is a valid concern for CodeReview which doesn't mean the code is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key insight is that I didn't have to check if any of the choices made at current position, say x, from game set S lead to a position, say x -S<sub>i</sub> ,  that will guarantee a loss for the opponent.Rather for any position that leads to loss I had to mark all further positions reachable from the current position using all the selections from the subset S as winning positions. Following is the code:

```
def winner(n_i, n_t, t_k):
    output = [False]*(n_i + 1)
    for j in t_k:
        output[j] = True
    for i in range(1, n_i + 1):
        if output[i]:
            continue
        for j in t_k:
            if i+j < n_i +1:
                output[i+j] = True
    return 'Little Deepu' if output[n_i] else 'Kate' 

num_test = int(input())

for i in range(num_test):
    num_items,num_take_outs = map(int, input().split())
    take_outs = list(map(int, input().split()))
    print(winner(num_items, num_take_outs, take_outs))
```